# 95 Integra LS starter selection

Tags: starter, integra

[95 Acura Integra:](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/42026/95-integra-starter) I purchased a remanufactured starter from Advanced Automotive and viewed this [youtube for instruction](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=90ED9iJ7ek4)   I have yet to start the replacement but may start it tomorrow.

Although this video did not provide footage of the bolts and wiring removal, it did raise an issue of remanufacture failure and the comments from others seem to support this:

[Starter Purchase options include](https://shop.advanceautoparts.com/web/PartSearchCmd?storeId=10151&catalogId=10051&pageId=partTypeList&suggestion=&actionSrc=Form&langId=-1&vehicleIdSearch=30649&vehicle_30649=1995%20%3A%20Acura%20%3A%20Integra%20LS%20%3A%201.8L%201834CC%20L4%20FI%20VIN%3A%20B18B1&searchTerm=starter&searchedFrom=header):

1. Carquest Remanufactured $124
2. Carquest New $138,$141
3. Denso Remanufactured  $205, $210

After viewing the video and comments, I am inclined to return the remanufactured starter (the new version is merely $16 more).

## QUESTION

That being said, is it better to go with the new Carquest or the Remanufactured Denso?

If you have experience with a starter replacement please state this in your response and the make / model / year of the vehicle.  Any lessons learned or pitfalls to avoid are highly appreciated.  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I've been in your situation before and I referenced Carid's write up on [New VS Remanufactured](https://www.carid.com/articles/starters-and-alternators-reman-vs-new.html) which states what is involved in the remanufacturing:

> A remanufactured part is one that has undergone a major teardown and
>   inspection. It has had all its wear-and-tear components replaced with
>   new ones. Remanufactured parts often distinguish themselves by
>   mirroring updates and improvements the OE manufacturer has made to
>   subsequent new parts. The reman company has tested the final product
>   once it's been assembled and before it's boxed up for resale. The
>   average shopper may look at a remanufactured part and think that it's
>   new, it will look that good. In general, remanufactured parts carry
>   the same warranty as a similar new part from the same supplier.

Historically some remanufactured parts are somewhat cheaper by up to half the cost.  To me, that is a factor but since you've acknowledged the price difference isn't much then consider the other factors.

### Quality

You've already stated that several have issued a concern or problem with the remanufactured so do you really want to risk the purchase?

### Time

The Acura starter isn't a complicated install but if you do purchase the reman and it does fail you should consider what more time invested to remove it again and install a newer one.  When I look at a job I factor what my hourly time is worth.  So is it worth you doing it twice for the price difference of the part?

### Warranty

This wasn't mentioned but I consider it a factor.  Some warranties I've seen for remanufactured parts are less then factory or OEM replacements.  Look at the reviews and see if the starter fails at a certain point.  Is it error by design possibly?

Comment: @DarthVader: excellent quesions.  What did you end up doing and what line of reasoning did you use?

Comment: I ended up buying new because the warranty was better in the end.

Comment: @gatorback if you did find it helpful you can always +1, too.